# How to implement activation phrase like "Hey Cortana" in SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: win-universal-app, speech-recognition

In the **SpeechAndTTS** samples in Universal Windows demo apps ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs)), even the continuous dictation examples requires the user to click on a button to start the recognizer.
[image]

So my question is how can we implement an always listening SpeechRecognizer? Activated when hearing something like "Hey Cortana" or "Okay Google".

[image]

The closest thing I can think of is

1. place a `SpeechRecognitionListConstraint` on the **speechRecoginzer**, which only listen to the "wake up word" ("Hey Cortana" for example)
2. In the `ResultGenerated` event handler, check if "Hey Cortana" is heard with medium/high confidence. If "Hey Cortana" is not heard, use `speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync()` to force the recognizer to listen again.
3. In the `Completed` event handler, use `speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync()` to force the recognizer to listen again.

Another thing I have checked is the `Timeouts` on the `speechRecognizer`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizertimeouts.aspx

But it appears we cannot have infinite `InitialSilenceTimeout`.

So, is there a straight-forward way to have a speechRecognizer that does not stop listening until the "wake up phrase" is heard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is how can we implement an always listening SpeechRecognizer? Activated when hearing something like "Hey Cortana" or "Okay Google".

As we know, we can't implement Cortana into our App when the app is already running in the foreground, we need to use [SpeechRecognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx). But we can done this job using [Continuous dictation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233380/how-to-implement-activation-phrase-like-hey-cortana-in-speechrecognizer).

> even the continuous dictation examples requires the user to click on a button to start the recognizer.

Yes, but this is because `await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync()` is in the button click event, the session start work in this event. To make it start without button click event, you can start this session in the `OnNavigateTo` method of the Page and stop this session in the `OnNavigateFrom` method. And of course you can stop this session when "wake up phrase" is heard.

I agree with your mind that you can force it to listen in the `Completed` event, but I prefer to use `speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync()` like this in the [SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed | completed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechcontinuousrecognitionsession.completed.aspx):

```cs
if (args.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
{
    if (args.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.TimeoutExceeded)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // Show the state on UI
        });

        await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }
    ...
}
```

And for the time limit, I just tested, by default the `Continuous dictation` will last about 5s without any voice at first and then went to the state time out. And I also tested to set the time like this:

```cs
speechRecognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
```

It worked by my side.

Actually for your scenario, you can refer to a official video: [Cortana and Speech Platform In Depth](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-716). In the sample of this video, it listens to two sentences: "take a note" and "save trip".

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the Cortana and Speech in Depth video. Great help!

Comment: Where can we have the source code for that "take a note" / "save a trip" app?

Comment: @Blaise, sorry, I didn't find it either, if you take look at the official [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand), it is also "AdventureWorks", but your scenario is not included in this version for now.